Problem in importing electrocardiogram dataset from scipy [Error: No module named 'scipy.datasets']
I tried to follow this example of scipy in peak analysis but when I imported the electrocardiogram dataset by from scipy.datasets import electrocardiogram , I got mentioned error.
I installed scipy again both through pip and conda but still no such package was added. Finally I found the electrocardiogram dataset using from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram . Can anyone explain why scipy.datasets does not exist for me? I am a Windows user, I have scipy version 1.9.1 and I use anaconda (no active environment).

You must probably upgrade your scipy version which is a bit old.

Thank you for your comment. the version was not the problem. not to mention, whenever I tried to install scipy by pip or conda as in pip install scipy, automatically version 1.9.1 was installed for me.

I solved my problem by installing scipy outside Jupyter notebook IDE and directly in the anaconda terminal by:
python -m pip install scipy

I still have 1.9.1 version after the installation but datasets package (folder) is now downloaded into my scipy folder (C:\Users<UserName>\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy)

"I use anaconda (no active environment)". As you've chosen Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager by choice by installing it, I'd caution you to stick with using Anaconda/conda as much as possible. Mixing and matching is a bad idea. You'll have more robust and portable environments. Leave pip use for only cases where there is no conda recipe.

Thank you for your comment but I also installed the package by conda inside jupyter but the problem was to install it inside anaconda terminal. as you see the problem was not pip alone.
